# How to fully expand a dictionary Json in dataframe view Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

Unable to fully expand the json file into a dataframe.

The file has the following structure

```
{
   "data" : {
      "currencies" : [
         {
            "code" : "USD",
            "id" : "1"
         },
         {
            "code" : "RUB",
            "id" : "2"
         },
         {
            "code" : "EUR",
            "id" : "3"
         },
         {
            "code" : "CHF",
            "id" : "756"
         }
      ],
      "dimensions" : {},
      "is_last_page" : 'true',
      "measures" : {
         "hits" : {
            "index" : 1,
            "title" : "Запросы",
            "type" : "number",
            "unit" : "count"
         },
         "shows" : {
            "index" : 2,
            "title" : "Видимые показы",
            "type" : "number",
            "unit" : "count"
         }
      },
      "periods" : [
         [
            "2022-07-01",
            "2022-07-28"
         ]
      ],
      "points" : [
         {
            "dimensions" : {},
            "measures" : [
               {
                  "hits" : 172565,
                  "shows" : 35032
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "report_title" : "Отчет за период 01.07.2022 - 28.07.2022",
      "total_rows" : 1,
      "totals" : {
         "2" : [
            {
               "hits" : 172565,
               "shows" : 35032
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "result" : "ok"
}
```

Now I can only expand in one line, in some cells there are unexpanded libraries and lists

http://joxi.ru/VrwX41ZtoY6jWm

Tried to do it through json_normalize

I need to expand completely into a table, please help

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect to expand the json into 1 dataframe. Can you put an example of what your desired output would look like?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here in this form
http://joxi.ru/l2ZbO0pHlWo0Z2
and if there are several periods in the report, so that it will be distributed over several more lines